# SQL trigger before insert append to ENUM

Tags: mysql, enums, triggers

I'm looking for a way to "append" a new `ENUM` value before the row gets inserted into the database.

I've read that the syntax for changing the `ENUM` should be like so:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY COLUMN `enum_column`
ENUM('ExistingVal1','ExistingVal2','NewVal1');
```

And I know creating a "BEFORE INSERT" trigger should look something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER `my_database`.`my_table_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    /*
    ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY COLUMN `enum_column`
    ENUM('ExistingVal1','ExistingVal2', NEW.`enum_column`);
    */
END
```

Now one of the problems is, that I don't know what the current existing values are.

So I think the following has to be done in chronological order:

1. Check if current value exists in the `ENUM` list of `enum_column`;

   - if exists go to 4
   - if not continue to 2
2. Get the existing values of that list.
3. Modify the `enum_colum` by giving the already existing values and appending the `NEW.enum_column` value.
4. Continue with insert.

Now I don't now how to get the existing values of an ENUM list easily (and how to format it properly so it can be used in the `ALTER TABLE` statement; maybe use `CONCAT`?).

p.s.

This seems like a hell of a lot of trouble for just appending a new value to an existing `ENUM` list...

Comment: Yeah, I always suggest staying away from MySQL's ENUM data type. You definitely don't want to be running an alter table on every insert, especially since I don't think you actually can (not allowed in triggers). If you're looking into dynamically expanding an enum definition, why aren't you just using a VARCHAR?

Comment: @Uueerdo yep VARCHAR was already my plan B. I was just curious if it was actually possible to do something like this within a trigger.

Comment: As far as I remember, you cannot do DDL (structural changes) in triggers; and even if you could, `ALTER TABLE` (even just to add an ENUM value) basically involves copying the entire table behind the scenes. _Also, you could get the enum values by parsing results from information_schema.columns`._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html says:

> The trigger cannot use statements that explicitly or implicitly begin or end a transaction ...

This includes DDL statements like `ALTER TABLE`.

The whole point of ENUM is that you restrict the values that you can insert into the column. The proper way to use ENUM is for a list of values that *won't* change.

If you intend to allow inserting any value without restriction, because you're going to add it to the ENUM if it isn't already in the list, then why not just use a VARCHAR?

If you're uncomfortable with the storage space required by VARCHAR, and you want to use a TINYINT or SMALLINT, then use a lookup table where you store the string values, and then store only the integer value in `my_table`.

But if you do that, you can't use a trigger to pre-populate values in the lookup table. Your table would have an integer column, so there's no column in `NEW.*` that would hold the string.

So you need to make sure the string is in the lookup table *before* you `INSERT INTO my_table`, and get the integer id corresponding to your value.

Comment: This is indeed what @Uueerdo already said in the comments. Thanks for the link and the idea to use a TINYINT with a lookup table, didn't think of that myself. I'll just do some more thinking but I'm getting really tempted to just use VARCHAR.